# What is the meaning of the "i" icon at the start of this line of code?

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse

I'm Using Spring, and I find many "i" icon at the start of the line. what does these mean?

[this is screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZlZ.png)

[image: code]

Comment: "i" means _info_ (problem levels: _error_, _warning_, _info_). Hover it to get more information about this specific info marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a spell checking info.

SessionFactory is definitly a property of HibernateTransactionManager.